# for a piston-prop aircraft, why "V max excess power" equals Vmd and "V max excess thrust" equals Vmp?

Tags: aircraft-performance, aircraft-physics

as what i read from books, on thrust-velocity and power-velocity curves for a piston-prop airplane

1. V max excess power= Vmd
2. V max excess thrust= Vmp

these two values are just so clicking, and i couldn't figure out what's the physics behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Power in aviation physics is Thrust × Velocity.  The best *combination* of these two is V max excess power, meaning (because of the drag curve) that no other speed will give a better rate of climb.

V max excess thrust is a slower speed because prop efficiency curve (thrust curve) *declines with airspeed*.  By slowing down, the *greatest difference in thrust to drag* is achieved (even though drag is slightly greater).  This allows the plane to *climb* at a higher angle, albeit at a slower speed.

V max excess thrust is also referred to as Vx, and V max excess power is Vy.

Comment: thanks for the answer! i entirely agree with what you said. but sorry for i didn't declare my question clearly lately, what i really wanna ask is why at a speed where an aircraft gets minimum drag gets maximun excess power, and vice versa.

Comment: @masterolof remember, "power" is Thrust × Velocity. At minimum drag plane uses least amount of thrust to counteract drag from lift, leaving all "excess" thrust to do things like climb.